# Convert particular string to last day of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a dataset in SQL Server and I need to transform one of the columns.

The string (`nvarchar(max)`) is a combination of the year and week of year, so the 8th week of 2021 looks like `202108`, the 32nd week of 2019 looks like `201932`, and so on.

What I need is to convert this into the last day of the month of the given week, so for `202302`, I need `01/31/2023`, in datetime format. I've tried a few different methods like `CAST()` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help, but it really depends on how you count weeks.   Perhaps a calendar table would be a better option.

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (202108)
,(201932)
,(202302)
 
Select * 
      ,NewVal = EOMonth(dateadd(week,try_convert(int,right(SomeCol,2)),convert(date,left(SomeCol,4)+'0101')))
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol NewVal
202108  2021-02-28
201932  2019-08-31
202302  2023-01-31
```

Comment: I expected a `-1` when adding the week, so I tested...... This seems OK. (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/Q8E9jlRb _

Comment: This got it for me immediately, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> in datetime format

Once more for those in back: **datetime values do not have a human-readable format**. Anything you see indicating otherwise is a convenience provided by the tooling.

Your goal at the database level should be to return a basic datetime value, and let the client code worry about the formatting. But we can do that:

```
EOMonth(DATEADD(week, cast(right([MyColumn],2) as int),CONVERT(datetime, left([MyColumn], 4) + '0101')))
```

Of course, the main key here is [the `EOMonth()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Everything else is just string parsing

Answer (score -1):

data Thanks John Cappelletti

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50));
Insert Into @YourTable
([SomeCol]) Values 
 ('202108')
,('201932')
,('202302');
```

query

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(wk,cast(right([SomeCol],2) as int),DATEADD(yy,cast((left([SomeCol],4)) as int)-1900,0))-1 AS WeekEnd
from  @YourTable
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/epb8mCoZ)

Comment: Why is this better/different than the answer from John C. ?

Comment: I used only data from it